# Yet Another Inequality in Information Theory

Tags: inequality, information-theory

Consider the following Markov chain:

\begin{equation}
  X^n \rightarrow W \rightarrow Y^n
\end{equation}

The notation $X^n$ is read as $X^n := (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$. Let $W$ take values in a set of cardinality $2^{nR}$ and let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be distributed independently according to $X$. I am interested in *whether the following statement is true*:

\begin{equation}
  \max_i I(X_i;Y_i) \leq R
\end{equation}

Note that proving

\begin{equation}
  \min_i I(X_i;Y_i) \leq R
\end{equation}

is fairly straight-forward. First, by means of the data processing inequality, we can argue that

\begin{equation}
  I(X^n;Y^n) \leq I(X^n;W) \leq H(W) \leq nR
\end{equation}

After that it suffices to produce a lower bound on $I(X^n;Y^n)$ as follows:

\begin{align}
  I(X^n;Y^n) &= H(X^n) - H(X^n \mid Y^n) \\
             &= nH(X) - H(X^n \mid Y^n) \\
             &= nH(X) - \sum_{i=1}^n H(X_i \mid X^{i-1}, Y^n) \\
             &\geq nH(X) - \sum_{i=1}^n H(X_i \mid Y_i) \\
             &= \sum_{i=1}^n I(X_i;Y_i) \\
             &\geq n \min_i I(X_i;Y_i)
\end{align}

Thus, $nR \geq n \min_i I(X_i;Y_i)$ and the second statement follows. Can we produce a similar result for the first claim?